# Inherit properties of a UITextfield

Tags: ios, swift2

I am new to Swift programming and I have a few textfields with similar properties. Can I create one textfield with defined properties and then extend them to other textfields. `num` inherits properties like `borderColor` and `borderWidth` from `textfield1`.

```
class TextElement: UITextField {
     var textfiedl1: UITextField = UITextField(frame:CGRectMake(38,383,299,44))
     textfield1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
     textfield1.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
}


class TextElement2 : UITextField {
     var num: TextElement = TextElement(frame: CGRectMake(38,416,299,44))
     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        num.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.addSubview(num)
}
```

This does not give any output. The simulator screen is blank. Any solution for this.

Comment: Your `TextElement` is a `UITextField` that creates a **different** `UITextField` and then seems to do nothing with it.  Is that really what you intended?

Comment: No. What i want to do is create a textfield then extend it to another one so that i don't have to write the borderWidth, borderColor etc again for new textfield.

Comment: Is there way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is completely off the top of my head (not tested) but I think you want something along the lines of the following:

**Base Class:**

```
class BaseTextField: UITextField {

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**Sub Class:**

```
class YourTextField: BaseTextField {

    init(frame: CGRect, backgroundColor: UIColor) {
        super.init()
        self.frame = frame
        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**Usage in Viewcontroller:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let textField = YourTextField(frame: CGRectMake(38, 416, 299, 44), backgroundColor: UIColor.redColor())
        self.view.addSubview(textField)
    }

}
```

**Note:**

You probably want to actually do something in `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` but for here I left the default implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question, when i addSubview(YourTextField) it does not show. But addSubview(baseClass.textfield) works fine.

Comment: I just tried this in a project and it worked for me. I've updated how I used it in the answer above to give a little more context. Make sure you're adding the textfield in a view controller and not from within the `UITextField` class itself.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is a *helper object*. Lightweight structs are perfect for this. Create a struct embodying the configuration features. Give the struct a method that you can call, passing `self` as a parameter, allowing the struct to configure your text field (warning: this is Swift 3):

```
struct TFConfig {
    let borderColor = UIColor.gray().cgColor
    let borderWidth:CGFloat = 1.0
    func configure(_ tf:UITextField) {
        tf.layer.borderColor = borderColor
        tf.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    }
}

class MyTextField : UITextField {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        TFConfig().configure(self)
    }
}

// ... similarly for other text fields
```